# Swift: Can't add specific node from subclass to scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, subclass, skspritenode

I made a Subclass and would like to call an object in GameScene.
Here's my Subclass Code:

```
var star: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var node: SKNode = SKNode()

override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: UIColor!, size: CGSize) {
    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: size)
}

init(xAxis: CGFloat, yAxis: CGFloat, imageName: String) {
    super.init()
    star = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageName)

    self.xScale = 0.5
    self.yScale = 0.5
    self.position = CGPoint(x: xAxis, y: yAxis)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

I call Star in GameScene.swift (didMoveToView(view: SKView))

```
let star0 = Star(xAxis: 303.30904, yAxis: 542.928431, imageName: "3.1_1")
self.addChild(star0)
```

Unfortunately my node does not appear on the scene.
What do I have to change? Do I have to "addChild()" in my subclass-init?

Comment: In init you need to add star as a child of `self`

Comment: I can't tell what you are subclassing to be honest, if it is a SKNode then as @Paulw11 said you need to do self.addChild(star) in the init. If it isn't an SKNode subclass, you would want self.addChild(star0.star) in your didMoveToView